# how can i get elements from array which makes sum equals to given value

Tags: java

how can i find lowest number of integers in the array that sums up the given number. The program should ask user to input array of integers (“Input Array”) and the required sum (“Required Sum”). The output (“Output”) should list the lowest number of integers from the input array that sums up the “Required Sum”.

here i create the *function sum()* and declare array with some elements when read sum from user **45** it gives me output **25,25** but when i input **59** and **60** nothing shows on output

```
 public static void sum()
{


int arr[]={10,0,-1,20,25,30};
Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in);
int sum=in.nextInt();

int[] sub = new int[arr.length];
int temp = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
        {
            for (int j = i, col = 0; j < arr.length; j++, col++)
            {
                //add the value of input array one by one
                temp += arr[j];
                sub[col] = arr[j];
                   //if addition is equal to sum then print it
                 if (temp == sum)
                {
                  int total = 0;
                   for (int k = 0; k < sub.length; k++)
                  {
                          total += sub[k];
                       System.out.println(sub[k]);

                       //if total and sum are equal then leave the print
                        if (total == sum)
                        {
                               System.out.println();
                            break;
                        }
                     }
                }
                //if temp is greater than sum are equal then clear the sub array, set temp value and leave the loop for next
               if (temp > sum)
                {
                    temp = 0;
                   break;
                }
            }
        }

}
```

Output Example:

**Input Array :** `[10, 0, -1, 20, 25, 30]`

**Required Sum:** `45`
**Output:** `[20, 25]`

**Required Sum:** `59`
**Output:** `[10, -1, 20, 30]`

**Required Sum:** `60`
**Output:** `[10, 20, 30]`

Comment: Approach is fundamentally incorrect, as you are adding numbers to temp, but there would be two path with in one you'll pick the current number and other you will not. Look for Subset Sub Problem, here is one link related with that. https://algorithms.tutorialhorizon.com/dynamic-programming-subset-sum-problem/

Answer (score 2):

```
import java.util.*;
public class Runner
{

    public static void find(int[] A, int currSum, int index, int sum,int[] solution) 
    {
            if (currSum == sum) 
        {

                  System.out.print("Output: [");
                  for (int i = 0; i < solution.length; i++) 
            {
                        if (solution[i] == 1) 
                {
                    if(A[i]!=0)
                    {
                                System.out.print("  " + A[i]);
                    }
                        }
                }
                  System.out.print(" ]\n");

            }
     else if (index == A.length) 
        {
                  return;
            } 
        else 
        {
                  solution[index] = 1;// select the element
                  currSum += A[index];
                  find(A, currSum, index + 1, sum, solution);
                  currSum -= A[index];  
                  solution[index] = 0;// do not select the element
                  find(A, currSum, index + 1, sum, solution);
            }
          return;
      }


    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Scanner in =new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("How many integer you have to insert: ");
        int n=in.nextInt();
        int []A=new int[n];
        System.out.println("\nEnter elements in Array:\n ");
        for(int i=0;i<A.length;i++)
        {
            A[i]=in.nextInt();
        }
        System.out.println("\nEnter required sum: ");
        int sum=in.nextInt();
            int[] solution = new int[A.length];
            find(A, 0, 0, sum, solution);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please find below program which I feel to be ideal for your scenario.
The Solution might not be optimal with memory and time consideration which you can optimize by based on your scenario.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;


public class Subset {

    static public void main (String[] ab)
    {
        int s[] = {10, 0, -1, 20, 25, 30};
        int sum = 45;
        ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> lis = subsets(s,sum);
        Iterator<ArrayList<Integer>> t1 = lis.iterator();
        while (t1.hasNext()) {
            List<Integer> t2= t1.next();
            int count = 0;
            Iterator<Integer> t3 = t2.iterator();
            while (t3.hasNext()) {
                count = count+ t3.next();
            }
            if(count ==sum)
                System.out.println(t2);
        }

    }

    public static  ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> subsets(int[] S,int sum) {
        if (S == null)
            return null;

        Arrays.sort(S);

        ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> result = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();

        for (int i = 0; i < S.length; i++) {
            ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> temp = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();

            //get sets that are already in result
            for (ArrayList<Integer> a : result) {
                temp.add(new ArrayList<Integer>(a));
            }

            //add S[i] to existing sets
            for (ArrayList<Integer> a : temp) {
                a.add(S[i]);
            }

            //add S[i] only as a set
            ArrayList<Integer> single = new ArrayList<Integer>();
            single.add(S[i]);
            temp.add(single);

            result.addAll(temp);
        }

        //add empty set
        result.add(new ArrayList<Integer>());

        return result;
    }
}
```

Hope this was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

try this code using simple arrays
i created sets from user entered array and print all of them and sets with sum equal to user entered sum i`m showing solution and the element count foe better understanding.

```
import java.util.*;
public class Main{


    public static void set(int[] temp,int sum){
     int n=temp.length;

        for (int i = 0; i < (1<<n); i++) 
        {  int sumc=0;
        int count=0;
            System.out.print("{ "); 

            // Print current subset 
            for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) 

                // (1<<j) is a number with jth bit 1 
                // so when we 'and' them with the 
                // subset number we get which numbers 
                // are present in the subset and which 
                // are not 
                if ((i & (1 << j)) > 0) {
                    System.out.print(temp[j] + " "); 
                    sumc=sumc+temp[j];     
                    count++;
                }
                if(sum==sumc){
            System.out.println("}"+" sum :"+sumc +" solution with "+count+" elements"); 
                }else{
                    System.out.println("}");
                }
        } 


    }



    public static void main(String args[]){
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("enter size of array : ");
        int n=sc.nextInt();
        int[] a=new int[n];


        int sum;
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
            System.out.print("enter "+i+" element value of array : ");
            a[i]=sc.nextInt();
            System.out.println();
        }
        System.out.println("enter sum : ");
        sum=sc.nextInt();
        set(a,sum);
    }
}
```

output :

[image: output of this code with]

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.*;
public class sum2
{
    public static Stack<Integer> find(int A[],int currSum,int index,int sum,int solution[],Stack<Integer> s)
    {
        if(currSum==sum)
        {
            int len=s.size();
            if(len<=s.size() ) 
              { 
                  s.clear();
              }      
            for(int i=0;i<solution.length;i++)
                {
                    if(solution[i]==1) {
                        if(A[i]!=0 )
                        {
                            s.push(A[i]);
                        }
                    }   
                }
            len=s.size();
            return s;   
        }           
        else if(index==A.length)
        {
            return s ;
        }
        else 
        {
            solution[index]=1;
            currSum+=A[index];
            find(A,currSum,index+1,sum,solution,s);
            currSum-=A[index];
            solution[index]=0;
            find(A,currSum,index+1,sum,solution,s);
            return s;   
        }
    }
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter Array size");
        int size=sc.nextInt();
        int A[] =new int[size];
        System.out.println("Enter elements");
        for(int i=0;i<A.length;i++)
        {
            A[i]=sc.nextInt();
        }
        System.out.println("Enter sum");
        int sum=sc.nextInt();
        int solution[]=new int[A.length];
        Stack<Integer> s=new Stack<Integer>();
        Arrays.sort(A);
        find(A,0,0,sum,solution,s);
        System.out.print("Output:" +s); 
    }   
}
```

It took almost 3 days

Answer (score 0):

One way is to find all subset of the array and then sum each of the subset and check if it matches.
Below is my code:

```
    public static void findAllPairs(int[] nums, int requiredSum) {
            // Get the length of the input array
            int n = nums.length;
    
            List<List<Integer>> res = new ArrayList<>();
    
            // Loop through all possible subsets
            // using bit manipulation
            for (int i = 0; i < (1 << n); i++) {
    
                // Loop through all elements
                // of the input array
                List<Integer> row = new ArrayList<>();
                for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
    
                    // Check if the jth bit is set
                    // in the current subset
    
                    if ((i & (1 << j)) != 0) {
    
                        // If the jth bit is set,
                        // add the jth
                        // element to the subset
                        //System.out.print(nums[j] + " ");
                        row.add(nums[j]);
                    }
                }
                if (!row.isEmpty() && row.stream().map(h -> h).reduce((a, b) -> a + b).get().intValue() == requiredSum) {
                    res.add(row);
                }
                //System.out.println();
            }
            System.out.println(res);
    }
```

Result for Sum =50: [[20, 30], [0, 20, 30]]